# Are these substring count assumptions incorrect for any javascript/javascript-library/mvc code blocks?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am creating an application for my department at work which includes the ability of the user to add custom blocks of javascript (or anything javascript-based such as jQuery, similar to the way WordPress allows the user to add custom blocks). I am adding simple front-end-only validation (no backend validation under the assumption that no one in my department will try any frontend tricks to get around the validation).

To me it seems a given that the substring count of non-string left braces must equal the substring count of non-string right braces. For example, this validates:

```
function myFunction() {

    alert('This is a string');

}
```

but this does not:

```
function myFunction() {

    alert('This is a string');

}}
```

I am also assuming similar things for parentheses, as this will not validate:

```
function myFunction() {

    alert('Hi'));

}
```

but this will be fine:

```
$("#myDiv").fadeIn(500, function () {
    $(this).css({"color" : "green"});
});
```

For the life of me I cannot think of any non-string exceptions that invalidate (no pun intended) my validation assumptions. Am I incorrect?

Comment: how would you handle function)( }{ ? You need to check order in addition to amount

Comment: It's a pretty simple validation for now...I'm looping through every character using a for loop - and - if (custom_js.charAt(i) === 'x'),  then incrementing character matches, then comparing counts at end of loop...anything complex will be dealt with as users complain to me that "it doesn't work" :)

Comment: Well, not sure what is the question then. As an extremely simple validation it will work, but even cases like function(){ console.log("}") will pass the validation. Would recommend using a library suited for this

Comment: It's an imperfect solution...I know strings like that will pass....I have a label to tell users not to use } { ) ( inside strings. For v1.0 I cannot think of any exceptions and based on this post I think that there aren't any

Comment: yeah go ahead, every { needs to have a matching }